# about multilingual wordpress website

Tags: internationalization, wordpress

I have a big interrogation about the internationalization process in Wordpress.
I want to internationalize an existing WP site, the content must be available in 2 languages : English and French. The user can switch  the site language clicking on a flag.

My question is about the PO/MO files used with the two core functions : `__()` and `_e()`
When you translate an existing site (theme, plugins) with these functions, It's only allow to change the main website language setting in the wp-config.php file  :

```
define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR');
```

With this process, your website can manage only one language at time.

But, if you want to run a website with 2 languages, you have to use an internationalization plugin.
I start using the polylang plugin but i would like someone to confirm that and I saw that my site has a lot of plugins which has their own PO/MO file and are already internationalize with  `__()` and `_e()` functions.

Does anybody can confirm me that before I div into internationalization with polylang ?

Greetings,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I would ask this question on the Wordpress Stackexchange page:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

As far as I know, Polylang should do the job.

An alternative is a Multisite WP installation and this:
https://github.com/lloc/Multisite-Language-Switcher/wiki

Comment: OK, I'll ask this on the dedicated WP forum : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71035/about-multilingual-wordpress-website